# Reading the Coordinates of a Shape File using ARCPY

Tags: python, shapefile, arcpy

I have a list of shape files in a directory and I am trying to extract the coordinates of each shape file using `arcpy`.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is sort of broad, so this answer is rather general :)

If you have ArcGIS 10.1+, then you can [use an arcpy.da.SearchCursor to loop through features](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000) in a shapefile and extract the geometry.

The example code below is for points. [Ref. the Esri documentation on reading geometries for lines or polygons](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000001t000000) (the basic theory is identical, the implementation is a bit more complex) for more detail. To repeat for multiple shapefiles in the same script, just add an additional `for` loop around the SearchCursor loop.

```
import arcpy

infc = ### your shapefile here

# Enter for loop for each feature
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infc, ["OID@", "SHAPE@"]):
    # Print the current multipoint's ID
    #
    print("Feature {0}:".format(row[0]))

    # For each point in the multipoint feature,
    #  print the x,y coordinates
    for pnt in row[1]:
        print("{0}, {1}".format(pnt.X, pnt.Y))
```

For 10.0 or earlier, you need to [use an arcpy.SearchCursor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000001t000000).

```
import arcpy

infc = ### your shapefile here

# Identify the geometry field
desc = arcpy.Describe(infc)
shapefieldname = desc.ShapeFieldName

# Create search cursor
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(infc)

# Enter for loop for each feature/row
for row in rows:
    # Create the geometry object 'feat'
    feat = row.getValue(shapefieldname)
    pnt = feat.getPart()

    # Print x,y coordinates of current point
    print pnt.X, pnt.Y
```